# Creating parallel threads using Win 32 API

Tags: c++, winapi, parallel-processing

Here is the problem:
I have two sparse matrices described as vector of triplets.
The task is to write multiplication function for them using parallel processing with Win 32 API. So I need to know how do I:

1) Create a thread in Win 32 API

2) Pass input parameters for it

3) Get return value.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: "Process" changed for "Thread"

Comment: Parallel processes or threads?

Comment: Threads, you are right.

Comment: Well, unless the matrices are truly huge, the overhead of spinning up threads is going to outweigh the benefits. What's more, if you care about performance, you should use a format other than triplets if you want to multiply two matrices.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Skyline + OpenMP, i guess. But this case is for study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer to your question is `CreateProcess` and `GetExitCodeProcess`.

But the solution to your problem isn't another process at all, it's more threads.  And probably OpenMP is a much more suitable mechanism than creating your own threads.

If you have to use the Win32 API directly for threads, the process is something like:

- Build a work item descriptor by allocating some memory, storing pointers to the real data, indexes for what this thread is going to work on, etc.  Use a structure to keep this organized.
- Call `CreateThread` and pass the address of the work item descriptor.
- In your thread procedure, cast the pointer back to a structure pointer, access your work item descriptor, and process the data.
- In your main thread, call `WaitForMultipleObjects` to join with the worker threads.

For even greater efficiency, you can use the Windows thread pool and call `QueueUserWorkItem`.  But while you won't have to create threads yourself, you'd then need event handles to join tasks back to the main thread.  It's about the same amount of code I suspect.

Comment: Yep, OpenMP is a way better and I used it couple of times before. But I got to use Win API in this case for some reasons (tutor said so :) )
So,  can you explain how do I start a thread, please?

Comment: Ok, well `CreateThread` will be a lot simpler to use than separate processes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What should I do to avoid waiting for all threads? It's like I have 100+ tasks and 4 threads available, so I want each thread to take next task without waiting for others.

Comment: @PavelOganesyan if you're multiplying known-size matrices I would determine the core-count on the machine, do the math for dividing out how many slabs each thread (one pre core) will be handling, setup the appropriate data structure for getting work-assignments to each thread, then fire them all off, with the current thread picking up the modulus if there is any left over, then just wait for all threads to finish via a WaitForMultipleObjects and you're done. There are several samples for doing this around the web and even on SO. If done right, no locks are required.

Comment: "OpenMP is a much more suitable mechanism than creating your own threads." Why?

Comment: @mk1: Because OpenMP is much easier to use, for the type of problems it is designed to solve.  And this problem is exactly the kind OpenMP was designed to solve (iterated processing, where it's desired to split the loop among several threads).  You want to explicitly use threads in other cases, such as with long-running background tasks, which don't fit into OpenMP very well at all.  And for parallel network I/O, you should use work items and the thread pool, because OpenMP doesn't fit and explicit threads require non-trivial management.

Comment: @mk1: OpenMP uses a thread pool and has work allocation algorithms. Scheduling is performed by the OS. Some CPU architectures, typically DSPs, control all available arithmetic units from a single thread, performing separate instructions on each. Others support SIMD, which multiple of the same operation in parallel from a single thread. But these do not qualify as multiple "cores", rather multiple arithmetic units coupled to a single execution control unit.

Comment: @mk1: I am not your personal tutor. If you are unfamiliar with a term I use, I expect you to look it up. Honestly if you've never heard of SIMD before you are ill-equipped to have this discussion.

Comment: @benvoigt thanks for your help nevertheless. I am just trying to wrap my head around that statement. Other than that it makes sense. Thank you again.